# SQL json_array_get - to search an object instead of position

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I am trying to get a value from a column in the following query:

```
SELECT 
    json_array_get(transactions.tags,0) as category,
    transactions.tags, 
    transactions.date as transaction_date,
    transactions.amount,
    CAST(transactions.amount as DECIMAL(20, 2)) as amount_banking,
    transactions.balance,
    opportunity.osc_score_previous_conduct
FROM "decisionengine"."public"."app_banking_transaction" AS "transactions"
LEFT JOIN 
    "decisionengine"."public"."app_banking_transactionbankdetail" AS "transactionsDetails" 
ON 
    "transactionsDetails".id  = "transactions".transactionBankDetail_id 
    
LEFT JOIN 
    "decisionengine"."public"."app_banking_bankingdetail" AS "banking" 
ON 
    "transactionsDetails".bankingDetail_id  = "banking".id 
    
LEFT JOIN 
    "decisionengine"."public"."app_banking_opportunitydetail" AS "opportunity" 
ON 
    "banking".opportunity_id  = "opportunity".id 
LIMIT 5
```

[image: Query results]

On the tags columns sometimes there will be an object with the node category, I want to extract the value of category if this node is present in that JSON.

I can see that json_array_get, allows me to get a position in the array, is there a way using this or how can I amend my query to get the value of category?

---

EDIT

```
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT * FROM (SELECT tags FROM "decisionengine"."public"."app_banking_transaction" LIMIT 10) AS t (json_string)
)

SELECT
    reduce(
        CAST (json_string as ARRAY(MAP(VARCHAR, VARCHAR))),
        map(),
        (s, x) -> map_concat(s,x), 
        s -> s
    )['category']
FROM dataset
```

I get the error

[image: sql error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access `category` values you could use next json path: `$.[?(@.category)].category` (would return array with values), but json path support in Athena is not that great, so you will need to perform some transformations - first casting json to array of maps, then joining them with `reduce` to one map and finally extracting `category` value from the resulting map:

```sql
WITH dataset AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES   
       ( JSON '[{"category": "test"},{"prop":2}]'),
       ( JSON '[{"id":"1"}]'),                   
       ( JSON '[{"category": "test1"}, {"prop":2}]')
 ) AS t (json_string))


SELECT
 reduce(
   CAST (json_string as ARRAY(MAP(VARCHAR, VARCHAR))),
   map(),
   (s, x) -> map_concat(s,x), 
   s -> s
 )['category']
FROM dataset
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| test |
|  |
| test1 |

Comment: I should have mention is a federate query, despite of this, I tested your sql and it worked but I am having trouble translating it to my sql, I get an error Cannot cast varchar to array(map(varchar, varchar)): i have ammended my question to add the modification of your sql, however if this works I cant see how I will join this with the rest of my table

Comment: @Manza try `JSON tag` in your query, or `CAST(tag AS JSON)`

Comment: JSON_PARSE(tags) works, :) do i need to do a join to get th eother columns? I am bit confused on this part sorry

Comment: @Manza then next should be `json_parse(tags)`

Comment: @Manza I would say you don't need the whole `with dataset as ...` - I used it just to create test data, you can use the `reduce(...)` as part of you original query (instead of `json_array_get(transactions.tags,0) as category,`)